How to frame certain cells with tabular?
I want to frame certain cells in a tabular table with a red border. In this example all cells with a F. I make a dirty hack and put the table in a tikz node and draw then red lines, but I hope there is a better solution.
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \sffamily
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
    \arrayrulewidth=1pt
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \rowcolors[\hline]{2}{col2}{col3}
    \begin{tabular}{P{0.15\textwidth}|P{0.25\textwidth}|P{0.15\textwidth}|P{0.15\textwidth}|P{0.15\textwidth}|P{0.15\textwidth}}
        \rowcolor{col1}
        \arraycolor{white}\bfseries column1 & \arraycolor{white}\bfseries column2 & \arraycolor{white}\bfseries column3 & \arraycolor{white}\bfseries column4 & \arraycolor{white}\bfseries column5 & \arraycolor{white}\bfseries column6\\
        1F & 1F & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        2F & 2F & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
        3F & 3F & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
        4F & 4F & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4\\
        5F & 5F & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}




Use tabularray:

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}[]{
    colspec={
            Q[0.15\textwidth]
            Q[0.25\textwidth]
            Q[0.15\textwidth]
            Q[0.15\textwidth]
            Q[0.15\textwidth]
            Q[0.15\textwidth]
            Q[0.15\textwidth]
        },
    row{1-Z}={c, m},
    row{even}={bg=lightgray!50},
    row{odd}={bg=lightgray},
    row{1}={font=\bfseries,bg=cyan!80!black,fg=white,},
    vline{2-Z} = {2-Z}{1pt, white},
    hline{1-Z} = {1-Z}{1pt, white, leftpos=0, rightpos=0},
    %
    hline{2,Z} = {1,2}{1pt, red, leftpos = 1, rightpos = 1},
    vline{1,3} = {2-Z}{1pt, red,abovepos = 1, belowpos = 1},
        }
    column1 & column2 & column3 & column4 & column5 & column6 \\
    1F      & 1F      & 1       & 1       & 1       & 1       \\
    2F      & 2F      & 2       & 2       & 2       & 2       \\
    3F      & 3F      & 3       & 3       & 3       & 3       \\
    4F      & 4F      & 4       & 4       & 4       & 4       \\
    5F      & 5F      & 5       & 5       & 5       & 5       \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix. The red frame is drawn by using the command \Block and its key draw.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sffamily
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{6}{p[c]{0.12\linewidth}}}[hvlines-except-borders]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{cyan}{1}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{gray!10}
\Body
  \RowStyle[color=white,bold]{}
  column1 & column2 & column3 & column4 & column5 & column6\\
  \Block[transparent,draw=red]{5-2}{}
  1F & 1F & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  2F & 2F & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
  3F & 3F & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
  4F & 4F & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4\\
  5F & 5F & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

You need several compilations (because nicematrix uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

